# python provide arguments to a function with single quotes

Tags: python

I have a function that provides the other functions its arguments

```
def errata_eus_repo(rhel_ver, cv_name):
    rhel_check = "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Extended Update Support" + " " + rhel_ver
    cv_name_errat = []
    for eus_repo in erra_eus_repo:
        errata = eus_repo[0]
        product = eus_repo[1]
        if product == rhel_check:
            cv_name_errat.extend([cv_name, errata])
            return cv_name_errat

def filter_ver(rhel_ver):
    regex = re.compile('\d{1}\.\d{1}')
    if not regex.match(rhel_ver):
        return False
    return True

for cv_rhel_ver in name_rhel:
    if not filter_ver(cv_rhel_ver):
        cv_name = str(cv_rhel_ver)
    if filter_ver(str(cv_rhel_ver)):
        rhel_ver = str(cv_rhel_ver)

    errata_eus_lst = errata_eus_repo(str(rhel_ver), str(cv_name))
    print(errata_eus_lst)
```

When I call `errata_eus_repo`, I don't get results

```
 errata_eus_lst = errata_eus_repo(str(rhel_ver), str(cv_name))
```

However, If I send the variables directly to the function I get the correct results.

I thought that the issue might have been to provide double quotes to the arguments `errata_eus_repo(str("rhel_ver"), str("cv_name"))`, but I am still getting no results. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the original value of `name_rhel`?

Comment: Your indentation is cockeyed.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes will only serve to pass the literal variable name instead of the data that variable contains. Your problem is in how you're using variables in the iteration cycle.

You are initializing only one variable on each iteration in the cycle, either `rhel_ver` or `cv_name`. The for loop should be giving you an error.